# Group Policy to run IE at logon not working

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I am trying to make it so that Internet Explorer starts with my companies Intranet page every time a user logs on to a Terminal Server, but I can't get it to work.

I am using Windows Server 2003 and the 'Run these programs at user logon' key and adding the following command, but it appears that it is being ignored by the GP (not listed in `gpresult \v` at all).

```
"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://dynedrewnett
iexplore http://dynedrewnett
```

I also have checked the Registry for the key that MS say should contain the prograns to run at logon, but the key does not exist -

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer\Run`

Does anybody know why this is not working? Thanks.

Comment: You say it doesn't get listed with `gpresult`... have you checked that replication is working? Have you tried `gpresult /force`?

Comment: You have created a custom adm template?

Comment: In what sense? I have a DC that holds our GPs and 4 Terminal Servers, so not sure what replication I should have (sorry, not very experienced with GP)? Is there a way I can check things like the last edit time of a GP that has been applied, to make sure that my changes are actually being applied (or that at least an attempt is being made to apply them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it could be something else since you mention that gpresult doesn't show the setting, have a look at the below.

From [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc975916.aspx)

> Unless the file is located in the %Systemroot% directory, you must
>   specify the fully qualified path to the file.

Try supplying the full path to `iexplore.exe`

Other things to check:

- Ensure that the GPO is applied to an OU that contains your user accounts, or use Loopback Policy processing.
- If you only recently made the change, ensure that the policy has been updated on the server you're testing on using `gpupdate`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMcKeown. I have edited as above (to see if it picks anything up at all) and I'm still not getting anything.

Comment: Added some additional things to check.

Comment: Thaks again. GP is being applied, just not the 'Run these programs at user logon' key. And have been logging off/on as well as running `GPupdate`, but sadly to no avail.

Comment: And your user accounts? Are they definitely located somewhere under the OU where you have applied the policy?

Comment: ^^ I take that back, GPupdate is actually adding the programs to the Registry key that I specified above, but not running anything at that time. Logging off and on then opens IE at log on (all 3 entries work).

Comment: That's normal behaviour. Sounds like it's working as expected now?

Comment: Kind of - still only on the servers that I have run GPupdate on. Not a massive issue if I have to do it on all for servers, as the key is machine based as opposed to user, but I just don't understand why it is not taking affect until I run GPUpdate? I thought that the GP was updated everytime a user logged in? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4303/discussion-between-chris-mckeown-and-david-gard)